# PHP : Get array from customs Objects functions

Tags: php, arrays, object

I search for an php function which would do the following process:

```
class Item{

private $id;

public function __construct($id){
    $this->id = $id
}

public function foo(){
    return 'Item_'.$this->id;
}
}

my_array = array();
$my_array[] = new Item(1);
$my_array[] = new Item(2);
$results = thefunctionimlookingfor($my_array, 'foo');

//which give :
//$results = {'Item_1', 'Item_2'}
```

Does anyone knows this function name?

Comment: should $result be a string or an array? ... Or an object maybe..? what are you looking for?

Comment: here $results is an array, containing all values return by the "foo" method of each objets in $my_array array.

Comment: Then check Bart van den Burg's answer. What was written above in your $results could have been a json string ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$results = array_map(function(Item $item) { return $item->foo(); }, $my_array);
```

And if you really need to have that function:

```
function applyMethod($data, $method) {
    return array_map(function($item) use ($method) {
        return $item->$method();
    }, $data);
}

$result = applyMethod($my_array, 'foo');
```